# Problems Installing slapd On Ubuntu Server 11.10

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-11.10

I know that there's a Ubuntu-specific StackExchange website, but I thought that I'd ask here because it's a server-specific question. If I'm wrong in my logic... Well, you people are better at this than I am! O=) On with the show!

I'm in the process of installing Oracle Database 11g R2 Standard Edition onto Ubuntu Server 11.10. I found a guide on the [Oracle Support Forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9596361) that walks you through the process fairly easily. Unfortunately, I'm running into issues installing one particular dependency: **slapd**.

When I go to install it, I get this error message:

```
(Reading database ... 64726 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking slapd (from .../slapd_2.4.25-1.1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ufw ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up slapd (2.4.25-1.1ubuntu4.1) ...
Usage: slappasswd [options]
-c format crypt(3) salt format
-g generate random password
-h hash password scheme
-n omit trailing newline
-s secret new password
-u generate RFC2307 values (default)
-v increase verbosity
-T file read file for new password
Creating initial configuration... Loading the initial configuration from the ldif file () failed with
the following error while running slapadd:
str2entry: invalid value for attributeType olcRootPW #0 (syntax 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15)
slapadd: could not parse entry (line=1051)
dpkg: error processing slapd (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
slapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After much Google searches and forum trolling, I have yet to find a definitive answer as to what's going wrong. The error messages seem straight forward enough, but I have no idea how to debug this. Can anyone offer some assistance? Again, if I'm asking in the wrong place, I apologize. If I'm indeed asking properly, then thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that I'm an idiot, and didn't read the documentation correctly. It turns out that you have to configure the server's hostname into `server.domain.com` format. You can do that by editing the `/etc/hosts` file. Happy hunting, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the preinstall script from the slapd-package calls slappasswd with the wrong arguments. This could be caused by updates which might have been applied to the tool slappasswd.

Download the debian package manually and extract its content with

```
dpkg -x <package name>
```

Have a look at the content of /debian/preinstall and see how slappasswd is called. You can modify the script, rebuild the package with

```
dpkg-buildpackage -tc -us -uc -rfakeroot
```

After that, simply install the built package:

```
dpkg -i <package name>
```